# Are there any good hardware VPN clients for SOHO use?

Tags: vpn, hardware

We've had numerous support hassles with software VPN clients.

Our remote devs need to connect to a number of different customer VPNs. Are there any reasonably priced VPN client boxes we could supply for them to use in their SOHO settings - so that they wouldn't need to get VPN client software working on their machines?

We need something that is flexible enough to work with common VPN servers - as we won't always be controlling that side of the connection.

Answer (score 2):

IME if you can't control both ends of a VPN then don't expect much success. IPSEC appeared to be a god send for solving these problems - but by the time it got implemented where were just too many different ways to configure it - even if you get your implementations from the same source.

Although there are relatively cheap off-the-shelf units which are straightforward to implement in a planned network - this approach does not scale down to SOHO installations where the internet connection may be via a modem which requires client software/non ethernet connection to the client device or a router which implements masquerading.

Have you tried using [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/index.php/about/testimonials.html)? Software will run on every flavour of Unix/Linux/POSIX including MacOSX and Microsoft NT based kernels, uses SSL so easily crosses NAT.

(note: SSL tunneling does have additional overheads which you don't have with IPSEC, however I've previously run VOIP over SSL based VPN - before openVPN was as mature as it is now - and had no detectable problems with jitter / frame loss, bandwidth overhead was relatively low too. I've not run OpenVPN over such a large network but given the same underlying technologies I wouldn't expect any issues)

Comment: +1 for OpenVPN. We use it a lot and it works a charm. Easy to configure, can easily handle multiple configurations for connections to a variety of targets. 
Plus: you can test a config for a particular connection, then simply mail it to everybody who needs to connect, with simple instructions on what to change (if anything). Recipient pops the config file into a specific folder, and Bob's your uncle.